# PHP/MySQL Encrypt ID within URl

Tags: php, mysql

i'm a newbie and I just built a CRUD system but its not secure at all. The edit page has the ID number in the URL and users can simple just randomly type ID's to access other records in the database.

http://example.com/example_edit.php?id=2

```
<?php

include_once("connection.php");


$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM mkregistrationchecklists WHERE login_id=".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY id DESC");
?>

<tbody>
<?php
while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {        

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$res['id']."</td>";
    echo "<td><span class='label ".$res['labelwarning']."'>".$res['status']."</span></td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['todaysdatetime']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['tag']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['serialnumber']."</td>";   
    echo "<td>".$res['currentequipment']."</td>"; 
    echo "<td>".$res['company']."</td>";  

     if ($res['status'] == "Submitted") {
    echo "<td><a href='page_read.php?id=$res[id]' class='btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'></a></td>";
} else{
    echo "<td><a href=\"page_edit.php?id=$res[id]\" class='btn btn-default fa fa-pencil-square'></a> | <a href=\"page_delete.php?id=$res[id]\" class='btn btn-danger fa fa-trash' onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\"></a></td>"; 
}

    echo "</tr>";



}
?>
</tbody>
```

What is the best approach in securing this?

Should i encrypt like this?

```
$secure_id = $_GET['id'];
$decryped_id = base64_decode($secure_id);
```

I updated my code, im saving the records according to the login_id but it still looks unprofessional with the id tag in the urls.

Comment: Base 64 encoding is *not* encryption. If you want to hide the id, you need to generate a token (a salted hash or, even better, a UUID), which you would store in the database alongside the other information for your record.

Comment: This is not related to security this is the development architecture. First remember if i am the user who is authorized to access records having IDs 1,2,3,4 then its does not matter that i can manually switch the page via URI and access data of all authorized ID. So its does not matter really if your user is authorized to access all record ID to edit the record. You should place a check (middleware) on the top of your page whether the requesting ID is authorized to the current user or not.

Comment: Also, the most important thing (as @Shailesh said) is checking permissions. Who cares if the user knows the item id, if you block unauthorized access anyway? If all you're doing is obscuring the information, that's called security by obscurity, and it is *not* a good idea. You need to check the user's authorization to view/update/delete the data, no matter what item id they provide.

Comment: If the user not authorized to access the data having for example ID 7 i.e. example_edit.php?id=7 then your code first check (on top) whether to allow this page to user or not.

Comment: @Ed Cottrell yeah you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add user / record owner unique identification into all SQL queries, typically :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = 1 AND user_id = 2";
```

with this approach you can be sure that user access only his records. Id of logged in user can be placed somewhere in `SESSION`.

Hiding or hashing ids is not recommended, it's a anti-pattern and [security through obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Comment: right but if he does not have user_id in his data table simply create a new table where you can place record_id and user_id relationship and check on fly.

Comment: Yes, absolutely, concrete implementation depends on his usecase, this is only for demonstration purposes.